# Increase speed of SQL insert on postgresql server on google cloud with around 2 million entries per minute

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, google-cloud-platform, sqlalchemy

I have 200 google cloud instances connected to an SQL Server also on google cloud. It is running on postgresql13, 2 cores, 7.5gb ram and 10gb of space. The instances are collecting sensor data the columns are varchar, int, and floats.

I am updating around 10000 (5 columns each) entries from each server per minute using pandas.to_sql and sqlalchemy using the following command `dfc.assign(source="{key}").to_sql(function, if_exists='append', con=engine, index=False)`.

The command creates another column during the save.

It takes around 10seconds to 1 minute for the instances to save. I don't know why the speed is so inconsistent between instances. Is there way to increase the speed and consistency of the save / insert?

Comment: Do you realize that the specs for your database instance puts it on the same order as my iPhone? Databases are affected by many factors. The two more important are disk IOPS and memory with CPU usually the least important. However, if you want better performance you need to figure out which ones are your limiting factors. Solution: benchmark. If you are lazy, try increasing the size of everything. For example disk IOPS is directly related to disk size in the cloud.

Comment: hahaha I did not realise that.. how do I benchmark?

Comment: Google Search is your friend. Google Cloud has metrics that you can use to measure and monitor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't enough information to answer that. Some point that can help you:

1)
I'd try getting the RAW SQL query and investigating it:

- How many indexes do exist in each table? Too many indexes may incur a lot of indexes to update, that can overload system resources
- Is there any trigger in this INSERT? What does it do? Probably you're supposed to look into each trigger and understand it as well
- When you say it takes 2 minutes to run, how were systems resources before it hit the server?

2. 

Do you have any replicas? If not, perhaps you can create replicas and segregate a part of this load

3)
Besides that, I'm wondering if you're using the right service for this job. Actually, that sounds not, so I suggest you to take a look at GCP BigQuery, Dataflow, and Dataproc services.
I think you can improve your architecture using Google's AI and ML services.

Comment: I thought BigQuery was meant for those google datasets? I can use it with my own datasets?

Comment: yes, you can create your own datasets, tables and apply some rules to automatically delete old data. It's worth to take look for your scenario